# UDP packet capturing on a servlet application running at GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sockets, servlets, openwrt

I have a code running in router that sends UDP packets(using Sendto() function and a string of data) to a particular server whose IP address and port number I will mention in my code.

I want to deploy a server application that could receive a UDP packet and store its information on server or somewhere else not sure right now.

I have decided to use Google app Engine for hosting my server side code which most probably will be having something like recvfrom() function to receive string.

So how and by using what API's can I start developing my server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine has a Preview release of a Socket API, but it does not let you create listening sockets. See *Limitations and restrictions* section at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

> You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets.

Comment: is their any way to encapsulate HTTP request/response in a UDP Datagram

Comment: Not in a standard way, as far as I know. It would be a custom implementation.

Comment: and any custom way to receive UDP packets using a java servelet on Google app Engine??

Comment: No, you can't receive UDP packets on App Engine.

Comment: It looks like if you're using java 8 you should be able to use sockets without limitations: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/
`Applications in the Java 8 runtime default to using native Java sockets with no restrictions`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Compute Engine](https://developers.google.com/compute/) to run any reasonable software on Google's cloud platform, including programs that receive UDP datagrams.  You must always pay for Compute Engine instances.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [newest edition of App Engine Socket docs for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/), if you're using java 8 runtime you should be able to use java sockets without limitations:

> Applications in the Java 8 runtime default to using native Java
>   sockets with no restrictions: Google recommends that you keep this
>   default.

That means that it should be possible to use [java.net.DatagramSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) or [java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html) freely to work with UDP.